# adjust plot parameters in R while plotting regsubsets object in R (more room below x axis)

Tags: r, visualization, regression

I'm trying to adjust the plotting parameters that I would normally do with `par(mar=c(10,4.1,4.1,2.1)` to allow for more room below the x-axis to plot these labels.  Right now the variable names are running off the screen.

Is it something with the leaps package or the `regsubsets` object that I'm plotting that doesn't recognize the `par(mar=c(10,4.1,4.1,2.1))`

Here's a boiled down example of what I'm trying to do.

```
require('leaps')
par(mar=c(10,4.1,4.1,2.1))
leaps <- regsubsets(mpg~disp+hp+drat+wt+qsec, data=mtcars, nbest=2, nvmax=5)
## artificially making labels longer... my labels are longer than this example dataset
labs <- sapply(leaps$xnames, function(x) paste(rep(x,5), collapse='')) 
plot(leaps, scale=c('adjr2'), labels=labs))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by the function (`plot.regsubsets()`) setting `mar` within the function body.  This overrides the `mar` that you set.

You can fix this by adding a `mar` argument to the `plot.regsubsets()` function and passing it to the `par()` call on line 3 of the function body:

```
plot.regsubsets<-function(x,labels=obj$xnames,main=NULL,
                          scale=c("bic","Cp","adjr2","r2"),
                          col=gray(seq(0,0.9,length=10)),mar = c(7,5,6,3)+0.1, ...){
    obj<-x
    lsum<-summary(obj)
    par(mar=mar)
    nmodels<-length(lsum$rsq)
    np<-obj$np
    propscale<-FALSE
    sscale<-pmatch(scale[1],c("bic","Cp","adjr2","r2"),nomatch=0)
    if (sscale==0)
        stop(paste("Unrecognised scale=",scale))
    if (propscale)
        stop(paste("Proportional scaling only for probabilities"))

    yscale<-switch(sscale,lsum$bic,lsum$cp,lsum$adjr2,lsum$rsq)
    up<-switch(sscale,-1,-1,1,1)

    index<-order(yscale*up)

    colorscale<- switch(sscale,
                        yscale,yscale,
                        -log(pmax(yscale,0.0001)),-log(pmax(yscale,0.0001)))

    image(z=t(ifelse(lsum$which[index,],
          colorscale[index],NA+max(colorscale)*1.5)),
          xaxt="n",yaxt="n",x=(1:np),y=1:nmodels,xlab="",ylab=scale[1],col=col)

    laspar<-par("las")
    on.exit(par(las=laspar))
    par(las=2)
    axis(1,at=1:np,labels=labels)
    axis(2,at=1:nmodels,labels=signif(yscale[index],2))

    if (!is.null(main))
        title(main=main)
    box()
    invisible(NULL)
}
```